# Laminate flooring edging

Tags: laminate-floor

I've installed some laminate flooring, and am coming to do the edging.  I'm aware that I can't fix the edging to the floor itself, but to the wall.  However, the wall is just brick.  I've tried using PVA and even silicone, but it's very difficult to get it to actually stay on the wall.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to something else I could use to fix the edging in place?

Comment: What kind of edging are you using?  quarter round?

Comment: That's right - quarter round

Answer (score 1):

You need a heavy duty construction adhesive.  PL, Loctite Power Grab, Liquid Nails, etc.

PL makes a trim adhesive that should work well on that brick - it sets up kind of slow but once it gets set up it will stick that trim to brick just fine.

Comment: This is good stuff. If then quarter round doesn't want to sit flat against the flooring/wall take a piece of scrap 1/4 plywood about 1 foot wide and as long or longer than the quarter round and lay it on the top edge of the quarter round and stack cinder blocks in the middle of it for about about 12 hrs. The idea is for the plywood to bow a bit which will push against the floor and wall.